# javascript regex obtained from a variable giving error on test: "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

in plain javascript: I am getting error when i run the below:

```
var arg_regex = 'myregex:/^[:a-z0-9\s!\\\/]+$/i';

regex_patt = arg_regex.replace(/^myregex:/,'');

if(regex_patt.test(stringtocheck)){
//good
} else {
//bad
}
```

error:

```
regex_patt.test is not a function
```

pl help. not able to figure why it would fail.

Comment: `regex_patt` is still a string, it's not a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Felix said:

```
regex_string = arg_regex.split('myregex:/').join('').split('/i').join('');
regex_patt = new RegExp(regex_string);
```

The RegExp object must be constructed from the string first.

In the above example, you're replacing a static string, so you can use `string.replace('staticTextToRemove','')` or use the `split` and `join` shown above.

I've heard `split().join()` is slightly more performant... and its a neat trick.

Comment: You have to replace even more... leaving the `/.../i` will result in unexpected behaviour (i.e. the characters are taken literally).

Comment: What happens to the regex flags in this example?

Comment: you mean the the `/` that you're used to seeing at the beginning and the end?  Those are stripped away.  You need those when declaring a regular expression literal, like you've been using.  But when you use the `RegExp` object, you pass in a string that isn't surrounded by `/`'s.

Comment: thx for explaining the regex 'object'. I read w3c website quite a few times about RegExp object, but could not figure what does it do which would turn the same expression into something which system would then start looking at as regular expr. tx to all!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to let regex_patt to be an object:

```
    regex_patt = eval(regex_patt);
```